# Определение при существительных – однородных членах

Tags: синтаксис, грамматика, однородные-члены, определения

**А теперь я хочу, чтобы в комментариях вы написали одну тему или вопрос, (который/которые) сегодня (волнует/волнуют) вас больше всего.**

"Определение ставится в форме множественного числа, если определение постпозитивно (даже при наличии разделительного союза между определяемыми словами), например: Мелкие повреждения кожи смазываются настойкой йода или бриллиантовой зеленью, предохраняющими от гнойничковых заболеваний." (http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm)

Но здесь множественное число как-то не очень будет звучать, ибо имеется в виду ЛИБО тема, ЛИБО вопрос, а в примере с сайта оба однородных члена предохраняют от гнойничковых заболеваний.

Answer (score 1):

А теперь я хочу, чтобы в комментариях вы написали **одну тему или вопрос, которые сегодня волнуют вас больше всего.**

**Множественное число выбирается для постпозитивного определения без учета других факторов**, такое согласование естественно воспринимается на слух.

Розенталь [http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm#з_05](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm#%D0%B7_05)

Comment: То есть в противном случае придаточное будет относиться только к слову "вопрос"?

Comment: Я эту тему понимаю так. Существует ФОРМАЛЬНОЕ решение, когда на первое место выдвинута проблема согласования в виде удобного восприятия предложения на слух. И существует СМЫСЛОВОЕ  решение, когда важно не исказить смысл.  В приведенном примере используется формальный принцип.  В препозиции уже названы два предмета, поэтому  на слух правильным кажется согласования во мн. числе. Смысловые отношения в этом случае грамматически не выражены, семантика здесьне так важна. В то же время вы задаете что-то одно (вопрос или тему), и по смыслу должно быть ед. число.